# Validations in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm writing optional validation in my user model. Based on which user registration step. I just started building it. The error I get is :

```
You need to supply at least one attribute
```

I added one validation to my model :

```
with_options :if => lambda { |u| u.current_step == "first" } do |user|
  user.validates :preference_missing? => true
end
```

If I change this to :

```
with_options :if => lambda { |u| u.current_step == "first" } do |user|
  user.validates :preference_missing?
end
```

I still get the same error. However if I change it to :

```
validate :preference_missing?
```

I don't get error about supplying at least one attribute. But since I do a validation on each step this will work but not work right.

Can someone point out where am I making mistake with current validations?

My preference method is :

```
private
def preference_missing?
    unless self.certificate? || self.ownership? || self.other?
      self.errors.add(:your_preference, "must be filled in.")
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you could do your custom validation with a condition:

```
validate :preference_missing?, if: -> { current_step == "first }
```

Hope that helps!